# Lightbox gallery in a link

Tags: slideshow

Here is what i try to get. Into WordPress a module plugin that allow me to make slideshow of image. create a portfolio name "castle" and another one name "bridge" and get 3-5 photo in each. Then, in a text, i will talk about a beautiful bridge name xyz and i like the name of the bridge to be a link, when i click this link, a modal window will appear with a slideshow ([light-box evolution](http://codecanyon.net/item/ez-plug-in-portfolio/full_screen_preview/2535532) is perfectly what i like), then somewhere else, when i talk about the caste abc i like the name to be a link, when click, show a slideshow of thos 4 image uploaded. so the question, what plugin do that ? thanks for the help !

the way things work in the theme Barely Corporate from ThemeBlvd is AWESOME, but i think it's custom work for there theme !

I try to find a way to get the behavior i whant, i am not promoting any theme or telling this is better that that, i just have seen behavior a like to replicate for my site

Comment: My research show that NextGEN gallery do the first part (making independant gallery) but cannot launch it from text link 50% done !

Comment: I have found :  Complete Gallery Manager for WordPress witch is a clone of NextGEN, but no luck for the link.. i think, cannot test it before 25$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can most likely use Easy FancyBox plugin (and maybe plus NextGen gallery) to achieve the effect.

The FAQ on the Easy FancyBox documents different things you can do:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-fancybox/faq/

For example, you can call lightbox of an hidden image with text link:

```
<a href="#hidden_image_id" class="fancybox">Castle abc</a>
<div style="display:none"><img id="hidden_image_id" src="hidden_image_url.jpg"></div>
```

So you'd apply this to a gallery shortcode that output element ID in it's dom:

```
<a href="#gallery-1" class="fancybox">Castle abc</a>
<div style="display:none">[gallery]</div>
```

If the native WordPress doesn't work, try the NextGen Gallery or others that would be compatible with how FancyBox tries to find the image sources.